# user not creating in django

Tags: python, django

I am working on an inventory management based project and i have downloaded a template "sneat". I have set all its urls according to django and also creates a signup and login views.
When user(any person who manages store) sign up it will go to login page. But user is not created i have tried code but when i check on database user is not created.
My 'signup.html' file is...

```
<form id="formAuthentication" class="mb-3" action="Login" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <!--{{ form.as_p }}-->
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="username"
                name="username"
                placeholder="Enter your username"
                autofocus
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required />
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 form-password-toggle">
              <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
              <div class="input-group input-group-merge">
                <input
                  type="password"
                  id="password"
                  class="form-control"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;&#xb7;"
                  aria-describedby="password"
                  required
                />
                <span class="input-group-text cursor-pointer"><i class="bx bx-hide"></i></span>
              </div>
            </div>
```

And my signup views are...

```
def Signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    
    # Check all required fields are filled
    if not username or not email or not password:
        messages.error(request, 'Please fill all required fields.')
        return redirect('Signup')

    # Check email is not already in use
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        messages.error(request, 'Email already exists.')
        return redirect('Signup')

    # Check email syntax is correct
    try:
        validate_email(email)
    except ValidationError:
        messages.error(request, 'Please enter a valid email address.')
        return redirect('Signup')

    # Create new user account
    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
    user.save()

    # Redirect to login page
    messages.success(request, 'Your account has been created. Please log in.')
    return redirect('Login')

return render(request, 'html/auth-register-basic.html')
```

And my urls are...

```
from django.urls import path
from login import views

urlpatterns=[
    path("",views.Index,name="Index"),
    path("Login",views.Login,name="Login"),
    path("Register",views.Register,name="Register"),
    path("forgetPassword",views.forgetPassword,name='forgetPassword'),
    path("Signup",views.Signup,name='Signup'),
    path("loginForm",views.loginForm,name="loginForm"),
    path("Account",views.Account,name="Account")
    
    
]
```

i don't know why it is happening.

Comment: Try changing `<form id="formAuthentication" class="mb-3" action="Login" method="POST">` to `<form id="formAuthentication" class="mb-3" action="{% url 'Signup' %}" method="POST">` so that the form is sent to the view with `"name=Signup"` in your urlpatterns.

Comment: But i have one more issue with login

Comment: Acutually issue is with 'base.html' file, I have created a base.html file and also modify the index.html file and now i want to merge these two files content by {%block content%},as usually we do our django project, but it is not mixing the content.

Comment: Understood, but that is a separate question, with code that is not shown here.  You should post another question with your `base.html`, `index.html`.

Comment: I am not able to post any question (Stackoverflow not allowing me this time), Can you please help me where should i put 'block content and end block' so it merges both files<
My base.html contains header,footer,sidebar and my index.html contains six bootstrap cards.
And i future i want to set a designing in that type that when i merge base.html in any other file then its content goes to header section,footer and sidebar and other file content goes to the center of the page,between these three (header,footer,sidebar)